# SAS proc import error: "Didn't see end for |varnames| element. Got -> ||"

Tags: sas, ascii, stata, importerror, non-ascii-characters

I am getting the following error when I try to import a .dta file:

> Didn't see end for ¦varnames¦ element. Got -> ¦¦
>   Requested Input File Is Invalid
>   ERROR: Import unsuccessful. See SAS Log for details.

The code I am using to import this file is simple, so it should not be a syntax issue. It is of the form below if interested:

> proc import datafile = "$path.\data.dta"
>   dbms=stata
>   out = data
>   run;

Any idea what this might be due to? The dataset I am trying to import consists of 4 character variables and ~10,000 obs.

Comment: What version of Stata created that file?  And what version of SAS do you have?

Comment: I'm using SAS 9.4. I did not create the Stata dataset, but have been able to open it using version 14. I tried saving it as version 13 and importing that file, but received the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS supports version 12 and earlier of Stata through `PROC IMPORT` currently.  You may want to try saving it as a version 12 file and see if that fixes the error.  Per @Nick-Cox in comments, see `saveold` command in Stata to do that.

See [PROC IMPORT documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/67382/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1rfs22st3zy3xn1hz9b9qsz4sp2.htm) for more details.

Comment: In Stata see `saveold`.